# Unable to Get The Access Token

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I've followed the instructions in this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/access-tokens) to get the access token but instead all I'm getting is the id token.

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: What is your scope value?

Comment: The client ID of my application which is registered in Azure B2C.

Comment: Okay, you could try specifying a scope in the application in B2C and use that scope's id instead.

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer? Any update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope you set should be incorrect.

You need to create two Azure AD applications for client and your API.

Please refer to [add a web API application to your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga) at first. It represents your API.

You will need to [configure scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga#configure-scopes) in this Azure AD app. Then you will get a scope like: `https://{your B2C tenant name}.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read`.

Then you should [grant permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-api-application?tabs=app-reg-ga#grant-permissions) in your another Azure AD app which represents your client. If you haven't created it, please refer to [Register a web application in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga).

Now you have all the configurations prepared.

Access this url in a browser:

```
https://{B2C tenant}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{B2C tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{B2C Policy name}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id={client id of the client Azure AD app}
&nonce=12345
&redirect_uri={redirect uri of the client Azure AD app}
&scope=https://{B2C tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read
&response_type=code
```

Login with your B2C account, you will get a `code` in the address bar.

Then send a request in Postman:

```
POST https://{B2C tenant}.b2clogin.com/{B2C tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{B2C Policy name}/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id={client id of the client Azure AD app}
&scope=https://{B2C tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/api/demo.read
&code={code from the pervious step}
&redirect_uri={redirect uri of the client Azure AD app}
&client_secret={client secret of the client Azure AD app}
```

Please note you should keep the same value for the `scope` of the 2 requests above. Otherwise, the access token may be missing based on my test.